# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Alexnet(cnn) + LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

currently making  human action recognition to detect a cheating kind on exam from CCTV using AlexNet+LSTM

My Data are raw image in a each class folder with like [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PVi6_U1cNseuZNsh0Eso9CF9XcvXIt-U?usp=sharing)

but i got error like this

ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:770 train_step  *
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:989 __call__  *
    input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:212 assert_input_compatibility  *
    raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +

ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_10 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
```

The error come when i do the model.fit

from what i read it said that the problem at the input_shape but i am still doesnt found the solution of my problem
the link of my code at colab can be found [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Z2zCae8BRCbTqDk0J-R9hhjUCX6S3cHN?usp=sharing),

i still dont understand what is the problem, i check the documentation for input_shape in TimeDistributed and it's the same for (timeSteps, height, width, channels)

is it from my ImageDataGenerator?or did i do wrong on making my model?

i would appreciate if anybody have the experience in this matter and try to help my problem

Thank you so much !

Comment: You should also show the code which is causing the error

Comment: @PrakashDahal i did, below the error there's my google colab link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error message says expected dimension 5D but received 4D input. Time distributed layer expects input of shape 5D.

**Working sample code:**

Consider a batch of 32 video samples, where each sample is a 128x128 RGB image with channels_last data format, across 10 timesteps. The batch input shape is `(32, 10, 128, 128, 3)`.

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(10, 128, 128, 3))
conv_2d_layer = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(conv_2d_layer)(inputs)
```

**Output:**

```
TensorShape([None, 10, 126, 126, 64])
```